# Is it possible to start Vault dev server on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hashicorp-vault

I have a Hashicorp Vault server running on an AWS EC2 instance at 127.0.0.1:8200.

In my Security Group's inbound rules, I have TCP 8200 enabled. But, I can't access Vault server from my local machine. I think it's because dev server is only available from inside EC2 instance (because it's running at 120.0.0.1, am I right?).

Is it possible to run Vault dev server at 0.0.0.0 instead, so I can access it from Internet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start your Vault server with the following command:

```
vault server -dev -dev-listen-address="0.0.0.0:8200"
```

You can also specify the address via the `VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS` environment variable.

Documentation [here](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/server.html#dev-options)

Comment: Wow great, I didn't see that option. Thank you!

Comment: Helpful, I was suspecting on my ruby client but starting server in this mode worked.