# HashiCorp Vault is not accessible out side of EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hashicorp-vault

I have installed HashiCorp vault in a Linux EC2 machine in AWS. I have unsealed it and allowed all the outbound traffic in Security Group. I am able to access the Vault service within EC2 instance using "http://localhost:8200". But I am unable to use the service when I try to hit the URL using public IPV4 of the EC2 from internet (ex: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8200).

Answer (score 4):

Check your network configurations.

There are a few things you can check:

- Your Security Group allow connections from your IP to the port 8200
- Your EC2 instance is in a public subnet.
- The NACL of public subnet allows connections to/from the port 8200 and to/from your IP.
- The Route Table of public subnet has attached an Internet Gateway.

If you validate this 4 points and still can't connect with the service, it can be a problem of the service listen-address is 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/server.html#dev-listen-address

In that case, you should start your HashiCorp Vault with the options:

```
-dev -dev-listen-address="0.0.0.0:8200"
```

This problem is described here:
[Is it possible to start Vault dev server on 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676084/is-it-possible-to-start-vault-dev-server-on-0-0-0-0-instead-of-127-0-0-1)